# {$contribution_aggregate} not outputting in message template

Tags: message-templates

I'm sure I'm missing something basic, but following the various documentation and examples I've seen I can't get {$contribution_aggregate} to actually output the aggregate contributions for a donor, it just outputs literally that text.

Steps I'm taking:

1. Find contributions, select the ones I want to include in a thank you letter
2. Select "Thank You Letters - print or email"
3. Select Group contributions by contact
4. Separator: Vertical table cell
5. Print and email options: Generate PDFs for printing (just don't want to email until it's correct of course)
6. Document body: to test I'm literally just putting {$contribution_aggregate} in the body
7. Click "Make Thank-you Letters"

And the resultant PDF literally just has {$contribution_aggreate} in it.

I'm on CiviCRM 5.9.0 on WordPress 5.0.3.

Thanks for any guidance anyone can provide!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look in your civicrm.settings.php (in wp-content/uploads/civicrm). There's a line that says:

define( 'CIVICRM_MAIL_SMARTY', 0 );

Change it to

define( 'CIVICRM_MAIL_SMARTY', 1 );

See https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/common-workflows/tokens-and-mail-merge/#smarty

Comment: D'oh! Thank you so much. Overlooked that clearly very important tidbit. Looks great now! Thanks again.

Comment: Great!  . . . . . . . .